# Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access, can't upload images

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am struggling with Firebase Storage. I can't upload any images to Storage although I have changed my rules a few times. The application is coded in SwiftUI and it has been working but now it is not.... I am getting the Response Error Code 403

These are my rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }

  }
}
```

Maybe someone can help

Comment: Make sure the user is signed into Firebase, you rule says that `auth != null;`

Comment: Those are Firestore's security rules and not Firebase storage one. Check linked answer for more information.

Comment: I checked and it is, I am using authentication....
I tried removing the auth != null; and write  allow read, write: if true and it is still not working